# How can I synchronize javascript code that depends on the response of multiple ajax requests?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety

Normally, I would use a callback function passed to the 'jQuery.getJSON' function to do something after the server responds. In this case, I have applied event handlers on some input elements, but these handlers should only execute after the success of multiple ajax requests. Basically I need to pause the execution of the event handler until some data I expect is avaliable.

In multi-threaded languages I would do it using mutexes/semaphores, but since javascript is single threaded I wonder if something like this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One manual way to do this is to queue up your AJAX calls in an array, and then count the number of responses you've received and wait until that count matches the size of your original queue (or, alternatively, pop the call out of the queue when the response is done, and you know you have everything when the queue is of 0 size).

You would have to check whether or not you are ready to proceed with a setTimeout call.

Alternatively, you may check out Deferred support in jQuery 1.5+

EDIT: A quick and dirty example of a manual approach:

```
var remoteCallA = function(){
    $.getJSON('someurl', function(){
        success++;
    });
};

var remoteCallB = function(){ 
    // etc
};

var whenAllDone = function(){
    // do something when everything is done
};

var checkAllDone = function(){
    if(success === remoteCalls.length){
        whenAllDone();
    } 
    else{ 
        setTimeout(checkAllDone, 1000);
    }
};

var remoteCalls = [remoteCallA, remoteCallB];
var success = 0;
for(var i = 0, length = remoteCalls.length; i++){
    remoteCalls[i]();
}

checkAllDone();
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm interested in the 'setTimeout' function which may be what I need. In the example you gave, lets say you used a small timeout(like 20 miliseconds) won't the recursion get too deep? It might cause a stack overflow.

Comment: @Thiado This isn't actually recursion, because the call to setTimeout() returns immediately and the function exits.  It just tells the browser 'hey, in 1000ms, run this'.

Answer (score 1):

javascript is event-based, so one approach is to throw an event each time a coordinated xhr gets its response.  The event handler tracks the responses and only proceeds when all are returned.

Or you can do the same thing without events, just by calling a method directly and coordinating the responses in there....

Answer (score 1):

I can give you a dirty solution. Create the function you want to execute once all queries return. Create another function to do the dispatch. Just like a semaphore/mutex, make a "synchronization" variable. Increment the variable for each of the calls. Then, in the dispatch function, decrement the variable and if zero, execute the function you want. Apply the dispatch function as the event handler for the ajax return (if you already have handlers that you *don't* want to pause, put it at the end of each existing handler).

Then, think of a more elegant solution.